# Flutter if statement inside a Text Widget without an else

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to display data from the database while some conditions are met, I am not sure if it is possible to use a `while loop` inside of a `Text` Widget, so I am using this code. However, by using this code, it forces me to write a value of text if the statement is not met, but instead I would like to skip those data if condition is not met and don't display anything, and `null` does not work inside of the `Text` widget. I was also wondering if there is a way to use a while loop inside a Text Widget?

```
Text(
   widget.userId == chats.senderid ||
   widget.userId == chats.receiverid ?
   chats.messageCont,
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this:

```
widget.userId == chats.senderid ||
   widget.userId == chats.receiverid ? Text(chats.messageCont): Container()
```

Comment: Thank you @Amon Chowdhury !